# How can i compare lossy image compression techniques?

Tags: image-processing, data-compression

I need to find which lossy image compression technique is the best. I chose to test JPEG, WebP and BPG. Which criteria can I choose for comparison apart from quality and speed of compression and how can I measure each criteria using tools like PSNR?

Comment: A better tool might be a human judging the quality of the compressed image.

Comment: "There are various tests for measuring distortion, but none are as good as the human eye. And we do not always agree on which images look better." (Matt Mahoney on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-image-compression-algorithm-and-what-is-the-Facebook-compression-algorithm))